# Disabling highlight on listView click for xaml Page Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have List in xaml Page:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListTypeView" ItemsSource="{Binding ResourceType}" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" HeightRequest="210" WidthRequest="300" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" RowHeight="30">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout StyleId="Settings_StackLayout" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0" Margin="50,0,0,0">
                    <Label FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="{Binding ResourceType}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100"></Label>
                    <Image x:Name="Image" Source="{Binding Checkbox}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="18" HeightRequest="18">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListTypeView}, Path=BindingContext.ListTypeChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I want to  disabling highlight on listView click
(remove list Selector which is blue in color default)

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it if you define TapGestureRecognizer on image then if you tap an image your list item should not be selected anyway. If you want to disable selector on item tap then you need to use different event - list item tapped

```
    lstItems.ItemTapped += LstItems_ItemTapped;
```

Then

```
 private void LstItems_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            //do whatever you need with selected item and reset it
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }
```